# Update opinion error Netlogo. (Beginner)

Tags: social-networking, netlogo

I'm trying to build a Netlogo model in which nodes in a network update their opinions based on the opinions (or 'participation) of others to whom they are linked in the network.

I made the following engine to update opinions

```
    to go 
 ask turtles [
set new-external-motivation (labda * external-motivation - ( 1 - labda ) * ( 1 - lpr ))]



  tick 
end 

to lpr
 ask turtles [
 set local-participation-rate ( (sum [participation] of link-neighbors) / (count link-neighbors) ) 
end
```

where labda is a slider variable that dictates the degree to which individuals use new participation information in their decisions and where lpr is the 'local participation rate' of the nodes the turtle is linked with. Each turtle has a participation variable which is either 0 or 1.

However, I'm getting the error "- expected 1 input on the right, a number" with the '1 - lpr' section of the code highlighted.

I'm not sure what wrong. Anyone who can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `lpr` should be a [reporter](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#procedures). Also, note that `lpr` is being called from *inside* the `ask turtles` in `go`. So you don't want to call `ask turtles` inside `lpr` as well; the way you have it, all turtles are asking all turtles to run the code in `lpr`, which is not what you want.

Perhaps you meant something like this:

```
to-report lpr
  report ( (sum [participation] of link-neighbors) / (count link-neighbors) )
end
```